# Column in pandas dataframe has lists as values. How do I create a version of this column but with only the first value in the list?

Tags: python, pandas, series

[image]

My current solution is below:

```
prices_real = []
    for item in sparkline['prices']: 
        prices_real.append(item[0])   
    sparkline['prices_real'] = prices_real
```

But I'm wondering if there is an easier way or a method I don't know about?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
sparkline = pd.DataFrame({"prices": [[1], [4]]})
sparkline
#   prices
# 0    [1]
# 1    [4]

sparkline["prices"] = sparkline["prices"].apply(lambda x: x[0])
sparkline
#    prices
# 0       1
# 1       4
```

Comment: Perfect answer except for one minor nitpick: PEP8 guidelines are not to use lowercase 'l' as a variable name, due to it looking too much like numeric 1

Comment: This gives an `object` dtype series. Not recommended.

Comment: @G.Anderson: Yeah, I agree. But I was not able to come up with a good name, I had just used `x` as the column name. After changing that to what the OP has in their dataframe I can use it though :)

Comment: @jpp: True, converting to numeric like in your answer is better (but not explicitly asked for by the OP).

Comment: @jpp: I agree. First I thought that your method would break down if it was not a list of strings (as it is here), making this slightly more general, but miraculously the `str` methods also work if it is not a list of strings...Sounds like bad naming to me, and a bit unexected.

Comment: @Graipher, Yeh, IMO if you go down `lambda` route, you might as will `from operator import itemgetter`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 aspects to your problem:

1. Extracting the first (and only) element of each list within your series.
2. Converting your series to numeric.

So you can use the `str` accessor followed by `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [['0.12312'], ['-5.32454'], ['0.563412'], ['-3.918324']]})

df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x'].str[0])

print(df, df.dtypes, sep='\n'*2)

          x
0  0.123120
1 -5.324540
2  0.563412
3 -3.918324

x    float64
dtype: object
```